# reading an int and storing it in a char * buffer in C

Tags: c, io

I have a file with integers. I want to write in a buffer those integers as chars (its ascii number). Because it is part of a bigger project please do not post different but please help me on that. What I especially need is chars to be stored in a buffer of type char *.

These are my declarations.

```
FILE *in;
  long io_len = 1000;    
 char * buffer;
    in=fopen("input.txt","a+");

    buffer = malloc(io_len * sizeof(*buffer));
      if(buffer == NULL){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

I am figuring out 2 sollutions.

If I write this one:

```
read_ret = read(in, buffer, io_len);
```

it reads from file in, io_len bytes and stores them in buffer. But it reads characters. So for example if I write 123 it will write to buffer 1,2,3 not the character with ascii number 123.

So I did this:

```
while((fscanf(in,"%d", &i))==1){
        printf(": %d\n", i);
    }
```

which reads the integers as I want. Now I am a little bit confused on how I will store them in buffer, as characters. I have tried this but it get me a segmentation fault.

```
while((fscanf(in,"%d", &i))==1){
        printf(": %d\n", i);
    buffer=(char) i;
    printf("Character in Buffer:%s\n",buffer);
    buffer++;
    }
```

Have in mind that later in my file I am writing my buffer somewhere else, so whatever I will do I want the pointer to be at the start of my char array(if it makes sense what I am saying)

Comment: Why do you need 1.5 MiB of space to store an integer?

Comment: I will not read only one integer. Do not look at the size, its a generic right now. My project only works if I give as an input the ascii numbers for my input, and I want to change it so as to give its integer equivalent. Instead of writing 0, write down 48 ans so on..

Comment: I'm sorry, but your clarification of what you are after is not clear to me at all.  You might need to look at your file open mode, too; the `"a+"` is not what I'd expect for reading a file.  Of course, you should also check that the `fopen()` succeeded.  But what is going to be in the file?  Maybe what you're after is `fread()`; it most certainly isn't `read()` unless you use `fileno(in)` as the file descriptor argument.  And depending on what's in your file, `fscanf()` might or might not be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final code should at least give you a warning about assigning an integer to a pointer in the line `buffer=(char) i;`. It looks like you want to dereference the pointer.

You are also printing a string when it looks like you really only want to print a character at a time.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
int character_index = 0;
while((fscanf(in,"%d", &i))==1){
        printf(": %d\n", i);
    buffer[character_index]=(char) i;
    printf("Character in Buffer:%c\n",buffer[character_index]);
    character_index++;
}
```